# Nest API - Unexpected behaviour when issuing commands from several devices

Tags: android, firebase, nest-api

I'm using the Nest API provided along with the Android sample app to write a plugin for [IoTivity](https://www.iotivity.org). The problem is that, when trying to issue commands from an Android device using the API, some of the them are successfully executed and some are not, or are being received after a very long time.

Besides that, if I monitor the target temperature from an Android device and modify it from the thermostat itself, the changes are being received correctly (the attributes of the Thermostat instance are changing accordingly), but if I try to change that target temperature from the Android device, while monitoring it, the thermostat goes haywire and changing the target temperature from the thermostat itself is not reflected any more by the Thermostat object, like I didn't make any change at all (however the thermostat displays the correct target temperature).

To put it in a nutshell: controlling the thermostat physically works until trying to control it with another device (let's say an Android device). After that the Thermostat instance is not updated correctly.

Thanks.